# Como por mais de um slideshow na mesma página

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow

Olá. Sou novo aqui mas achei que seria o lugar ideal para solucionar meu problema. Vamos lá.

Sou iniciante e Estou desenvolvendo uma página. Nessa página, criei um slideshow para apresentar as etapas de um determinado projeto. Meu problema é que quando faço outro slideshow, acabo repitindo o mesmo código e script. E acho que isso acaba gerando muito código. Teria alguma maneira de eu criar vários Slideshows usando o mesmo script? Irei upar o código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.top').click(function(){
        $('ul').toggleClass('active');
    })
})
    
    
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}


    var slideIndex2 = 1;
showSlides2(slideIndex2);

function plusSlides2(n) {
  showSlides2(slideIndex2 += n);
}

function currentSlide2(n) {
  showSlides2(slideIndex2 = n);
}

function showSlides2(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides2");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot2");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex2 = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex2 = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active2", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex2-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex2-1].className += " active2";
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
display: none;

}

.slideshow-container {
position: relative;
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
height: 550px;
background: #e6ffe6;
}

.mySlides img {
max-width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}


.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -24px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;   
}

.prev{
left: 0;
background: #009900;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
background: #009900;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: #009900;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #33cc33;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #009900;
}

.mySlides2 {
display: none;

}

.slideshow-container2 {
position: relative;
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
height: 550px;
background: #e6ffe6;
}

.mySlides2 img {
max-width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}


.prev2, .next2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -24px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;   
}

.prev2{
left: 0;
background: #009900;
}

.next2 {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
background: #009900;
}

.prev2:hover, .next2:hover {
  background-color: #009900;
}

.dot2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #33cc33;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active2, .dot2:hover {
  background-color: #009900;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_cobertura.css">
                
</head>

<body>
    
       
    <div class="row">

        </div>
    
        <div class="mid-column col-7">
              
            <div class="slideshow-container">

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="image/cobertura-verde/001.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="image/cobertura-verde/002.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="image/cobertura-verde/003.jpg">
            </div>
            
            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="image/cobertura-verde/004.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="image/cobertura-verde/005.jpg">
            </div>
                
                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

        </div>
                <br>

        <div>
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
            
        </div>
           
            
        <div class="slideshow-container2">

            <div class="mySlides2 fade">
                <img src="image/cobertura-verde/fase1/020.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides2 fade">
                <img src="image/cobertura-verde/fase1/021.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides2 fade">
                <img src="image/cobertura-verde/fase1/022.jpg">
            </div>
            
            <div class="mySlides2 fade">
                <img src="image/cobertura-verde/fase1/023.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides2 fade">
                <img src="image/cobertura-verde/fase1/024.jpg">
            </div>
                
            
        
            <small class="small"> Fotos do dia 16/03/2010 </small>
                
                <a class="prev2" onclick="plusSlides2(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                <a class="next2" onclick="plusSlides2(1)">&#10095;</a>

        </div>
                <br>

        <div>
            <span class="dot2" onclick="currentSlide2(1)"></span> 
            <span class="dot2" onclick="currentSlide2(2)"></span> 
            <span class="dot2" onclick="currentSlide2(3)"></span>
            <span class="dot2" onclick="currentSlide2(4)"></span>
            <span class="dot2" onclick="currentSlide2(5)"></span>
            
        </div>
```

Comment: cria um evento javascript para cada slide, no caso tu deve criar o evento com classes diferentes.

Comment: Fabiano, obrigado pela resposta. O evento no qual você diz seria no Script ne?

Comment: Acrescente 2 nas variáveis e nas classes ou ID do HTML.
Diferencie as propriedades dos dois códigos.

Answer (score 0):

O problema para reaproveitar esse código é que ele tem o seletor do slide dentro do código. Para poder reaproveitar as funções você precisa abstrair esse seletor para fora da função, passando para ela cada vez que criar usar um slideshow.

O código ficaria assim

```
var slideIndex = 1;
// Mantive o código mais próximo do original, mas é melhor trabalhar com getElementsById neste caso. 
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var slides2 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides2");
// ... N slides => var slideN = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlidesN");

var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
var dotsn = document.getElementsByClassName("dot2");
// ... N slides => var dotsN = document.getElementsByClassName("dotN");

showSlides(slideIndex, slides, dots);
showSlides(slideIndex, slides2, dots2);
// ... N slides => showSlides(slideIndex, slidesN, dotsN);

function plusSlides(n, slides, dots) { // acrescentando o parâmetro "slides"
  showSlides(slideIndex += n, slides, dots);
}
function currentSlide(n, slides, dots) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n, slides);
}
function showSlides(n, slides, dots) { // acrescentando o parâmetro "slides"
  var i;
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Existem formas mais simples de fazer slideshows, e este código tem alguns problemas, mas para fins didáticos é um bom ponto de partida.

Comment: Acho que entendi o que quis passar. Você disse que teria uma forma mais simples de se fazer um slideshow. Você teria algum material que eu pudesse ver ou estudar para tormar o meu código mais simples?

Comment: Se você quer fazer o slideshow, o seu código está ok e vc pode ir aprimorando com o tempo. Mas se sua intenção é só mostrar o slideshow, vc pode usar alguma lib pronta. Como está usando jquery, pode usar algum plugin de slideshow pra jquery por exemplo.

Comment: Sim. ele está funcionado. o que eu queria saber era o seguinte: se por acaso eu quisesse criar mais 1 slideshow na mesma página, eu tenho alguma maneira de reutilizar o código ou vou ter que fazer da maneira que estou fazendo? pois acho que desta forma que postei, estou gerando muito código e talvez na hora de carregar fique pesado. esta é a minha dúvida.

Comment: Você leu a minha resposta? Ali está o código pra vc reaproveitar sem precisar reescrever a mesma função várias vezes. Quanto a ficar pesado, não faz muita diferença ter várias funções ou uma só. Só muda mesmo para deixar o código mais fácil de ler e de manter.